# how do you make display:table-cell width:100% - 270px

Tags: css

here's my code:

```
    <div id="banner" style="position:absolute; top:0px; width:100%; background:url('../../images/banner_repeat.jpg'); background-repeat:repeat-x; <!-- border:solid pink 1px; -->"> 
        <ul id="banner_ul">
            <li id="wrm"><a href="http://whiterootmedia.com"><i>The homepage of White Root Media!</i></a></li>
            <li id="google"><a href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/b/115943543157099352927/115943543157099352927" target="_blank"><i>+1 us on Google!</i></a></li>
            <li id="facebook"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/White-Root-Media/194381903928501" target="_blank"><i>Like us on Facebook!</i></a></li>
            <li id="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/#!/WhiteRootMedia" target="_blank"><i>Tweet about us on Twitter!</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="container" style="<!-- border:solid yellow 1px -->; display: table;">
        <div id="content" style="padding-top:90px; display:table-cell; min-width:945px; <!-- width:100% - 270px; -->">
            This content will determine the height
        </div>
        <div id="right_column" style="display: table-cell; <!-- border:solid orange 1px; --> height:100%; width:270px; background-image:url('../../images/treetrunk7.png');background-repeat:repeat-y;">tree</div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer" style="position:relative; top:-1px; background-image:url('../../images/grass.png'); background-repeat:repeat-x; width:100%; height:100px;">grass</div>
```

here's the live page:
http://whiterootmedia.com/test/test4/

I would like the content div that is display:table-cell to go the full width of the page minus 270px. The tree should be all the way to the right.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Dusty

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning in the child div's

```
#foo {
    display: table;
    height: 400px;
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;   
}

#foo > div {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

#left {
    background: blue;
    left: 0;
    right: 200px;
}

#right {
    background: green;
    right: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

[click here for demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/37VCz/)

there are other methods of achieving the same effect such as changing the margins, I personally prefer the method above